# i3-msg doesn't move workspaces between multiple monitors consistently

Tags: multi-monitor, desktop-environment, i3, workspaces

I have two monitors; eDP1: primary (laptop's screen) and HDMI2, the external monitor. What I want to do is to use i3wm such that when I run a script (below), it put some workspaces on eDP1 and some on HDMI2. Using xrandr my HDMI2 is on the right side of eDP1:

```
xrandr --output HDMI2 --auto --right-of eDP1
```

Here is my script to achieve that:

```
#!/bin/sh

Out=HDMI2    

i3-msg "$workspace1"
i3-msg "move $workspace1 to output eDP1"
i3-msg "move $workspace2 to output eDP1"
i3-msg "move $workspace3 to output eDP1"
i3-msg "move $workspace4 to output eDP1"
i3-msg "move $workspace5 to output eDP1"
i3-msg "move $workspace6 to output eDP1"
i3-msg "move $workspace7 to output eDP1"
i3-msg "move $workspace8 to output eDP1"
i3-msg "move $workspace9 to output eDP1"
i3-msg "move $workspace10 to output $Out"
i3-msg "$workspace1"
# come back to workspace 1
```

But this doesn't work as expected. While I intend a fixed behavior, it put the screen randomly different by each run. At the moment these two commands works pretty fine in my config file and I easily move windows between monitors:

```
bindsym $mod+Ctrl+greater move workspace to output right
bindsym $mod+Ctrl+less move workspace to output left
```

---

*p.s. I'm on Archlinux and i3 is `4.16.1`*